# hover function on parent div conflict with child hover function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a hover function on a parent element and child event when hovering on the parent child hover function is not working.

I hover a hover function on univ div and heading div. When hovering on the univ div  heading div hover function is not working. How to make both hover function work.

```
        <div class="univ">
         <div class="sub-content">
             <div class="heading">XXXXXXXX</div>
             <div class="content"> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
             TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
            </div>
          </div>
        <div class="sub-content">
           <div class="heading">XXXXXXXX </div>
            <div class="content"> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
             TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
            </div>
         </div>
       <div class="sub-content">
           <div class="heading">XXXXXXXX</div>
            <div class="content"> TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
             TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
           </div>
     </div>
        </div>
```

Js

```
  $('.univ').hover(function(e){
   if($(e.target).hasClass('content')){
    alert('Inside Content');
    }
     else{
      }
       });



     $('.heading').hover(function(){
       $(this).parent().find('.content').addClass('xxx');
         });
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working version of hover adding a class:

https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/j2kxfd76/1/

And here's the code:

```
$('.univ').hover(function() {
  if ($(this).find('.sub-content').length>0) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});

$('.heading').hover(function() {
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  if( parent.hasClass('sub-content'))
    parent.addClass('active');
});
```